# Authentication with apache2 php pages and tomcat REST calls

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, tomcat, apache2

Hello smart people on stackoverflow,
I would be very happy if someone could point me to the right libraries/frameworks to do what I want.

We have the following web architecture set up.

```
 1. We have a tomcat server that offers REST services.
 2. We have an apache2 server that serves up php pages to users.
    a. Some of these php pages make REST calls to tomcat for data.
    b. Other php pages contain javascript that makes REST calls that are routed through apache2 via mod_proxy to tomcat. e.g. All request to http://myapache.com/PASSTOTOMCAT/rest/getSecureData would go to tomcat.
```

Now, I'm asked to add authentication to everything, both the user pages as well as the REST calls. It would obviously be ideal for the user to sign-in once for access to both.

What library can I use for this? I don't think I can use any php-based solution (ie. one that involves adding a ) because the pass-through url's won't have a chance to add this code and check for authentication. I think I need to use something built into apache2 itself.

One minor requirement is that I would like the user credentials stored in a mysql database as opposed to a file.

Am I over-thinking this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well it's been 5 days, so I guess I'll answer my own question...

I ended up using the new mod_auth_form for authentication because it lets you use a nice stylized webpage to log users in.
I also used mod_dbd to access user credentials in mysql.

I couldn't find a nice tutorial on this so I struggled through the installation and setup a bit, but if anyone cares, I created a set of instructions on my blog in case anyone else tries to do the same thing.

[Installation](http://kodingnotes.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/authentication-in-apache2-4-part-1-installation/)

[Setup](http://kodingnotes.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/authentication-in-apache2-4-part-2-setup/)